# Explain how $\sum_{k = 1}^n\frac{k^2}{2^{k - 1}} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\frac{\left(k + 1\right)^2}{2^k}$?

Tags: summation

Can someone explain simply why $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^n\dfrac{k^2}{2^{k - 1}} = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}\dfrac{\left(k + 1\right)^2}{2^k}$?
I don't get why we go from $k$ to $k+1$ in the numerator, please help me understand it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! At the moment, it hard to tell precisely what you are asking. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are asking why $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{2^{k-1}}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(k+1)^2}{2^k}.$$  This is a change of summation index.  We have $1\le k \le n$, so $0\le k-1 \le n-1$.  Now let $j=k-1$, so $0\le j \le n-1$, and 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^2}{2^{k-1}}=\sum_{k-1=0}^{n-1} \frac{(k-1+1)^2}{2^{k-1}}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{(j+1)^2}{2^j}.$$
Now just change $j$ to $k$ to obtain
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{(k+1)^2}{2^k}.$$

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you Rob

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark the answer accepted.

Comment: Done! Thanks again